# ioctlsocket() fails with 10045

Tags: c, windows, sockets, blocking, nonblocking

I have a fairly simple piece of C code which should create a non-blocking socket under Windows:

```
int iResult;
u_long iMode = 1;

WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1,1);       
WSADATA wsaData;                              

WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

client_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if (client_s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

iResult = ioctlsocket(client_s, FIONBIO, &iMode); 

if (iResult != NO_ERROR){
printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n",WSAGetLastError());
}
```

However, it always returns with error code 10045 which means unsupported operation on a socket. It is not described in the possible errors for `ioctlsocket()` and as I understand closer related to receiving processes.

I've already checked for errors thrown by the `WSAStartup()` but everything works correctly until then.

`client_s` is correctly defined as a socket so I don't really see the point of failure.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think this is because sockets are non-blocking by default. Did you check for that?

Comment: They behave unblocking if I use the MSG_PEEK flag in the recvfrom() function but then I can't receive anything anymore, the recvfrom returns always -1. If I don't use MSG_PEEK, the recvfrom() is blocking.

Comment: The code works for me (at least `ioctlsocket` returns 0) using _VStudio 2015_ on _Win10_.  I suppose that you have `#include <WinSock2.h>` (**before** `#include <Windows.h>`, if present). Did you try a newer _Windows Sockets_ version: e.g. `WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);`?

Comment: this may be depend from windows version, or some else. for me `ioctlsocket`  return 0 - no error. however in windows `non-blocking` socket is obsolete and UB. really windows used synchronous or asynchronous (so called overlapped) sockets. look for `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in `WSASocket`. `socket` is call `WSASocket` with overlapped flag - *The socket that is created will have the overlapped attribute as a default* (from *socket* function page). you need not non-blocking - but overlapped(asynchronous( i/o. this ioctl not need at all. obsolete

Comment: @unwind, no, sockets are not non-blocking by default.  (Not according to the documentation, anyway.)  The underlying handle is *asynchronous* by default, but that's not at all the same thing.

Comment: @CristiFati your thought about the "**before**" is quite a hint. I got this warning but because I develob against a third party application with a very complex structure, I did not know how to include winsock2 before windows header. I have fixed the issue by multithreading, which is better anyway because I can do better update handling. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Including _WinSock2.h_ after _Windows.h_ (which includes _WinSock.h_) triggers tons of compile errors (mainly redefinitions), it's a common known issue, I'd say. Anyway as I said before the code works fine for me (I don't know if it actually sets the NB flag, since I didn't do any further tests).